# when i do a query with spring data jpa , findTop10XX if the value is less the query takes a long time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

```
public interface AlarmRepository extends MongoRepository<Alarm, String> {

List<Alarm> queryFirst10ByHubAndDeletedAndDataspace(String idHub, boolean b, String dataspace, Pageable sort);

List<Alarm> queryTop10ByHubAndDeletedAndDataspace(String idHub, boolean b, String dataspace, Pageable sort);

List<Alarm> findTop10ByHubAndDeletedAndDataspace(String idHub, boolean b, String dataspace, Pageable sort);
}
```

index de hub in alarms

```
@CompoundIndex(name="alarm_hub_id_index", def = "{'hub.$id' : 1}")
@CompoundIndex(name="alarm_hub_id_dt_event_desc_index", def = "{'hub.$id' : 1, 'dtEvent' : -1}")
```

postmant get

```
/rest/titan/v1/alarms/historical?hub=62285d951a110632228d6a0e&dataspace=200&sort=dtEvent,desc
```

If the data number value is greater than or equal to that indicated in the top, the query time does not exceed 200ms, on the other hand, if the data is less than the value entered in the top or in the page, the query is very slow, even return a timeout

class Alarm

```
    @Document(collection="alarms")
@CompoundIndex(name="alarm_dt_event_dataspace_index", def = "{'dtEvent' : 1, 'dataspace' : 1}")
@CompoundIndex(name="alarm_hub_id_index", def = "{'hub.$id' : 1}")
@CompoundIndex(name="alarm_hub_id_dt_event_desc_index", def = "{'hub.$id' : 1, 'dtEvent' : -1}")
@CompoundIndex(name="alarm_hub_id_dt_event_desc_dataspace_index", def = "{'hub.$id' : 1, 'dtEvent' : -1, 'dataspace' : 1}")
public class Alarm extends CommonEntity implements Cloneable{
    //@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Date start Alarm")
    //@Field
    @Indexed(name = "dt_event_alarm_index",unique = false)
    private DateTime dtEvent;
    //@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Source of Alarm")
    @Field
    private Source source;
    @Field
    private String comments;
    @Field
    private Boolean active;
    //@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Severity of Alarm")
    @Field
    private Severity severity;
    //@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Detail of Alarm")
    @Field
    private DetailAlarm detail;
    //@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Hub of Alarm",required = false)
    @Field
    @DBRef
    private Hub hub;
    //@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Hub of Alarm",required = false)
    //@Indexed(name = "traffic_controller_alarm_index")
    @Field
    @DBRef
    private TrafficController trafficController;
    @Field
    private ElementTypeAlarm elementType;
    @Transient
    private String dtEventForKafka;
    @Transient
    private String dataspaceForKafka;
    ... geter seters 
}
```

Comment: can you explain your question a bit more by sending some code or any example

Comment: The examples of the query in the repository are in the question

Comment: are we having index on hub ?

Comment: What has this to do with JPA? You are using mongo?

Comment: spring data jpa

Comment: @jesuscabrera it cannot be jpa if you're using Mongo

Comment: Also, post the code of your Document class

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result